# No suggestions when code snippets are used in sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

For example, when i type `i` suggestions come with `if` statement. And I press `tabs` for selecting `if` snippet. i get this.

```
  if(condition) {
    // code...
  }
```

But inside this snippet I no longer get any suggestions. I have to type everything. Why is this happening? Please help.

Comment: do you pre-save your file with .extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocompletion inside snippets is disabled by default. You can enable it by changing the value of the `auto_complete_with_fields` preference to `true`:

```
// Controls if auto complete is shown when snippet fields are active.
// Only relevant if auto_complete_commit_on_tab is true.
"auto_complete_with_fields": true,
```

Comment: I think it is mainly so that pressing tab will always jump to the next snippet field - with autocompletion turned on, another snippet tab trigger could be executed instead, and the user might be surprised/confused and unable to jump to the next snippet field.