# PHP code snippet doesn't execute properly after another code snippet in Sublime text 3

Tags: php, sublimetext3, code-snippets

I have a PHP class and constructor snippet that I have created in sublime 3.

**Class**

```
snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
class ${1}
{
    ${2}
}
]]></content>
<!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet 
-->
<tabTrigger>cla</tabTrigger>
<!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger --
>
<scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

**Constructor**

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
public function __construct(${1})
{
    ${2}
}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>_c</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

Here's what I am trying to accomplish when the code snippet is triggered:

```
class Person
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }
}
```

Instead after I use the class snippet the constructor snippet doesn't trigger and the cursor moves to the end of the classes curly brace like so:

```
class Person
{
    _c
}//cursor is now here
```

Then I can go back through, go back delete the _c and hit the constructor trigger again and everything works just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No suggestions when code snippets are used in sublime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41842405/no-suggestions-when-code-snippets-are-used-in-sublime)

Answer (score 0):

Just set `"auto_complete_with_fields": true,` in your ST preferences, or manually trigger autocomplete after typing `_c` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.